# Inability to properly load Rtf to a RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, rtf

I have a custom RichTextBox that derives from the RichTextBox base class. Its purpose is to display formatted text. However, any Rtf loaded is displayed as simple text without any formatting: font, font-size, font-style etc.

I have tried the following code to load the Rtf: (Note: rtbEx is the extended richtextbox control; RTF is a string containing the Rtf)

1. Using a file stream:

   ```
   FileStream tempFile = File.Open(@"C:\RTF.rtf", FileMode.Open);
   tempFile.Position = 0;
   rtbEx.LoadFile(tempFile, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
   tempFile.Close();
   ```
2. Loading from the specified path:

   ```
   rtbEx.LoadFile(@"C:\Users\Wilbur Omae\Desktop\RTF.rtf", RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
   ```
3. Directly setting the Rtf:

   ```
   rtbEx.Rtf = RTF;
   ```

On checking the Rtf of the rtbEx, it seems to be perfect Rtf, yet it is displayed as plain text.

What could be the issue?

Update 1:
The custom RichTextBox is a control within a custom `Form` which it to be displayed as a TabPage.

Comment: This is a strange one. When I use as standard richtextbox class and load in a RTF file with some blod text, I have no issues with the formatting displaying. Could you maybe provide the RTF file and the custom class?

Comment: @DanGardner Here's the RTF: .

`{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}{\f1\fnil\fcharset0 Palatino Linotype;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs17\par
by \par
LoremIpsumDolor\par
LoremIpsumDolor \par
\par
\par
\b\fs16 Lorem\i ipsum\ul dolor\fs56 LoremIpsumDolor\ulnone\b0\i0\f1\fs30\par
}`.

.

Wordpad recognises and correctly opens the RTF file. However, when i replace my custom RichTextBox with the standard one, the formatting is still lost..

Is there something else that may hinder proper rendering of Rtf?

Comment: @WilburOmea That's interesting so using the standard `richtextbox` you still don't see the formatting? In my small example using your code on my machine it displays fine [see my screen grab here](http://pasteboard.co/2AMYgXbg0.png)

Comment: How complex is the application at the moment? Is there anything else going on that could be altering/preventing this? As a very basic debugging step if you create a new project with one form, and one `richtextbox` control and use only the lines of code above in the `InitializeComponent()` method, do you get any formatted output?

Comment: I don't know really since all these are workarounds when the process should be straightforward. I still can't pin down the underlying issue. Thanks for your help, though.

Comment: The application is quite complex. Let me try that and post back

Comment: Using a simple new Form: it works. Well, I guess I've got some debugging to do.

Comment: That's frustrating, at any other point do you interact with the text box or file reader?

Comment: When you find a solution (or if you need any more ideas) would you add it to the comments here or as an answer. I'm quite interested myself as to what the problem might be

Comment: @DanGardner Got any news?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Clipboard in this case :

```
 Clipboard.SetText(RichTextBox1.Rtf, TextDataFormat.Rtf);
```

and paste it

```
 RichTextBox1.Text= Clipboard.GetText()
```

It works for me .. try it

Comment: That leaves the RichTextBox empty. However, using the overloaded `Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Rtf)` displays the Rtf as ordinary text. Setting `RichTextBox1.Rtf = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Rtf)` displays plain text, which is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I ensured the Rtf was set only when the form had been shown by trapping the `Form.Shown` event as shown below:

```
public class SermonReader : Form
{
    public RichTextBoxEx rtbEx= new RichTextBoxEx();
    private string RTF = "";

    public SermonReader(string rtf)
    {
        RTF = rtf;

        Shown += new EventHandler(ehFormShown);
        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        TopLevel = false;

        Controls.Add(rtbEx);

        rtbEx.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }
    private void ehFormShown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rtbEx.Rtf = RTF;
    }
}
```

I don't know why the issue is this complicated but I hope this helps.

Any other solution? Feel free to comment or answer.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem with a richtextbox within a winformscontrol
within a dialog (MFC), the rtb should be filled with rtf, but
after setting RichTextBox.Rtf, loading from file or Clipboard it all was unformatted.
I could solved it by using Postmessage in OnInitDialog with UpdataData(FALSE) (Sets RichTextBox.Rtf again)
in the handler. seems as if creation yet was not complete ..

Comment: Your answer is hard to understand.  Putting your code in a code block would help.